# Render AEM pages in React dynamically independently of URL path

Tags: reactjs, react-router, aem, single-page-application

I have the need to be able to render any of the pages in my AEM model.json dynamically regardless of the current URL in a SPA React app.

My AEM model.json structure has pages following the `/<country>/<language>/rest/of/path` format, but I want to be able to strip the country/language and just use the rest of the URL path.

I am able to do this when I initialize the ManagerModel with a the desired path like this:

```
const path = `/path/to/<my_model>.model.json`

/* initialize the ModelManager with the path to the model.json */
ModelManager.initialize({ path })

/* 
  grab the desired section of the model and render by calling ReactDOM.render 
  By doing this I am able to render the section of the model that maps /us/en/user-account` for 
  example, and render the correct content even though the current browser path is  `/`
*/
ModelManager.getData(`/us/en/<page_to_load>`).then(render)
```

When I handle navigation with `history.push` (I use react-router), I want to be able to render another page following the same logic. By default, having executed `ModelManager.getData("/us/en/<page_to_load>")`, every page that I navigate to then renders that same portion of the model.

To fix this, I have tried many variations of `ModelManager.getData()` calls with no success. The only thing that I have been able to have any success with is dynamically passing the path to the next page to render to a callback function that is defined on the index.js level and passed down as a prop to App.js. The callback triggers another ReactDOM.render call and loads the page correctly regardless of what the actual URL path is. That code looks something like this:

```
<App
  reRender={(path) => {
    /* manipulate the path so that it properly maps to the correct AEM model data */
    const updatedPath = `/us/en/${path}`
    /* 
      this works, but causes another ReactDOM.render call every time that the current page is 
      changed 
    */
    ModelManager.getData(updatedPath).then(render) 
  }}
/>
```

There are also cases where the page that has been navigated to doesn't have a corresponding path in the modelStore mapping. I am able to handle that like this:

```
const pathToInsert = `/<country>/<language>/${window.location.pathname}.model.json`
ModelManager.modelStore.insertData(pathToInsert)
ModelManager.getData(pathToInsert).then(render)

/* 
  I have been having issues with this, but can get the newly inserted model to load properly by 
  re-routing back to the current path from the current path 
*/

this.props.history.push(window.location.pathname)
```

I have read and re-read the documentation [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@adobe/cq-spa-page-model-manager) and I am unable to figure out the correct way to do what I want to do. The above solutions work for the most part, but are pretty hacky and I would like to find out the proper way to accomplish this. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Im facing the same issue. Did you find the way to make it work?

Comment: My comment was too long so I answered my question, please refer to that answer. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I found a work around solution. The AEM library can't handle this requirement out of the box unfortunately. My solution was to make a wrapper for my App component. In that wrapper I initialize the model manager, clone the data and store it in local stage. Then you can conditionally modify the model and pass it along as a prop to your App component. If you have a good understanding of how AEM model data is mapped you should be able to figure out a way to display what you want. You can also fetch and insert models into your master model's ":children" prop (think that is the field name, have not looked in a while).

Comment: Thanks for your response. In our case, we made something similar. As you said, AEM Model Manager doesn´t provide a way to make this work, so you have to wrap it and modify the model to work for your case.